# How to convert rough integer year to minimal centuries + decades + years?

Tags: math

How would you make a basic algorithm to convert a year into the minimal number of centuries, decades, and years? Really I have more time frames than that: year, decade, century, thousand, million, billion. But whatever is easiest.

The basic problem is I would like to break down dates like `10248 years ago` into something like `{ thousand: -10, century: -2, decade: -4, year: -8 }`. What is a straightforward way of doing that, I have been sitting here for a while trying to wrap my brain around it but haven't gotten it to work.

```js
console.log(breakdownYearToParts(-10248));

function breakdownYearToParts(integer) {
  let n = integer
  const data = {}

  const thousand = n % 1000
  if (thousand) {
    data.thousand = thousand
    n = Math.floor(n / 1000)
  }

  const century = n % 100;
  if (century) {
    data.century = century;
    n = Math.floor(n / 100);
  }

  const decade = n % 10;
  if (decade) {
    data.decade = decade;
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }

  const year = n % 1;
  if (year) {
    data.year = year;
  }

  return data
}
```

I don't think I quite have it right, I don't know the theory behind how to do this accurately though I know it has something to do with modulus. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Modulus is giving you the remainder if you were to divide by 1000, 100, etc. To find your value for 1000s, it’d be floor division of n by 1000. Then you can subtract that value*1000 from n and do similar floor division by 100 for 100s, subtract from n again and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that finding the least significant digit first would simplify code.

```js
console.log(breakdownYearToParts(-10248));

function breakdownYearToParts(integer) {
  let n = integer
  const data = {}

  data.year = n % 10
  n = (n - data.year)/ 10 
  data.decade = n % 10
  n = (n - data.decade)/ 10 
  data.century = n % 10
  n = (n - data.century) / 10 
  data.thousand = n

  return data
}
```

Comment: Mind explaining how it works, how is it different from the other answer from JStewArt (which also appears to work)?

Comment: @Lance To not get too deep, what is unclear about  `data.year = n % 10`
  `n = (n - data.year)/ 10` is unclear?

Comment: I don't understand what it's doing, so everything I guess . To try and explain my thought process: `n % 10` tells you the remainder of dividing n by 10, but I don't see why that is meaningful. Why 10? And the `(n - data.year)/10`, why subtract by the year and divide by 10? I guess I just don't understand the basic math.

Comment: @Lance With `n = 12345`, `n % 10` gives 5.  And that is the `data.year`.  `(n - data.year)` is 12340 and 12340/10 is `n = 1234`.  We repeat then for the next digits: `data.decade, data.century, data.thousand`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a piece of code in C++ that I believe answers your question. in pseudo-code, it's:

```
//where n is your starting number(i.e. -10248)
//where x is the amount you extract (i.e. -10, -2, -4, -8)
//where y is the amount of time you are looking for (i.e. for decades it is 10, for centuries it is 100...)
x = ceil(n / y);

//then to prepare the number for the next calculation you subtract your previous answer while adjusting for its size in years.
n = n - x * y;
```

Here is the piece of code I wrote for your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float n = -10248;

    float thous, cent, dec, year;

    thous = ceil(n / 1000);
    cout << "thous: " << thous << endl;

    n = n - thous * 1000;

    cent = ceil(n / 100);
    cout << "cent: " << cent << endl;

    n = n - cent * 100;

    dec = ceil(n / 10);
    cout << "dec: " << dec << endl;

    n = n - dec * 10;

    year = ceil(n);
    cout << "year: " << year << endl;
}
```

it's output:

```
thous: -10
cent: -2
dec: -4
year: -8
```

Note: It is ceil() because you are working with a negative number but it would be floor() for a positive one.